# Tera Term - enable local echo

Tags: telnet, teraterm

**Hi everybody,**

### I have some question about a enable local echo in tera term. How can I enable local echo in tera term via command?

When I send a message from telnet server (device)

- "WON'T" Echo
- "DO" Echo

Tera term responds:

- "WON'T" ECHO

I know i can enable local echo in setup but I want a option to enable echo from my server.

Is exist any other option to enable local echo from server?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

If using the Tera Term scripting language, you can do something like:

```
setecho 1
```

https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/setecho.html